# Swift - Segue Double Clicked

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a function that checks the form input and then if valid based on boolean variable, it would initiate a performSegue to transition to the next stage.

I have 3 views for user registration:
1- Basic Details
2- Username
3- Account Verification

When i click on the button, it goes from Basic Details to Username view...and then immediately move to Account Verification. A print statement in the body of the ViewDidLoad function in Username ViewController prints to console twice (strange!).

Here is the body of the code I have:

```
@IBAction func proceedPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Proceed Pressed");
        if nameTextField.text != "" || emailTextField.text != "" || passwordTextField.text != "" || mobileTextField.text != ""
        {
             /*Check Formatting of Fields and Rules*/
            let validationResult = true
            /*Store in userObject for further processing*/
            if(validationResult == true)
            {
                //updateing objects
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectUsernameSegue", sender: sender);
            }


        }else{
            /*Display validation error on screen*/
            print("Some Fields are Empty!");
        }

    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "selectUsernameSegue") {
            // pass data to next view
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UsernameViewController
            destinationVC.userObject = self.userObject;

        }
    }
```

and the segue I have between the two views (1 & 2) is called selectUsernameSegue. Why is it showing 2nd view controller then moving directly to third?

Thanks,

UsernameViewController body:

```
class UsernameViewController: UIViewController {

    var userObject = UserClass();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("Email: " + userObject.email!);
    }
```

Comment: How have you wired the segue from Basic Details to Username? How are you triggering that segue?

Comment: show some code of the second view controller, this one looks okay apart from the malformed boolean logic.

Comment: @vacawama I wired it using storyboard and then gave it a name. and the controller above shows the trigger.

Comment: @luk2302 boolean is done this way for testing purposes. Updating the post.

Comment: Did you wire the segue from the button, or from the viewController icon at the top of the viewController?

Comment: @vacawama using the button.

Comment: That's your problem.  The segue will be triggered immediately when the button is pressed, and a second time when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`.  Instead, you should wire the segue from the viewController icon at the top of the viewController if you want to trigger it with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Comment: @vacawama That worked! Thanks for helping. Post as answer please so I can select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wired your segue from the button.

The segue will be triggered immediately when the button is pressed, and a second time when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Instead, you should wire the segue from the `viewController` icon at the top of the `viewController` if you want to trigger it with `performSegueWithIdentifier`:

[image: wiring segue]